# I'm trying to make an array work with user inputs

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, input

I would like to make a number array with numpy based on user inputs then find the mean median and mode of this array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, George. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question isn't very clear. What have you tried? In what way did it fail to do what you want?

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @Chris thanks i will  change this question based on your advice

Comment: Don't spend too much time on this task.  `numpy` arrays are best used for large amounts of data, amounts that are impractical to enter directly.  It's better to load the data from a file (e.g a `csv` format).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.asarray([int(i) for i in input().split()])

print(array.mean())
print(array.mode())
print(array.median())
```